# MockMvc does not return created resource in post response

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-rest, spring-boot-test, mockmvc

Normally when you post to a spring data rest endpoint the response contains the location header with the url to the newly created resource and the json representation of the new resource in its body.

But when I post to MockMvc like following:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class OrderRestTest {

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    @Autowired
    private OAuthHelper oAuthHelper;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {

        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
                .webAppContextSetup(context)
                .apply(springSecurity())
                .build();

    }

    @Test
    public void testSuperuserCanCreateOrder() throws Exception {

        RequestPostProcessor accessToken = oAuthHelper.addBearerToken("someSuperUser", "ROLE_SUPERUSER");

        Order order = new Order();
        order.salesMemo = "some sales memo";

        String responseFromTestRestTemplate = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(order);
        assertNotNull(responseFromTestRestTemplate);

        mockMvc.perform(
                post("/ErPApI/orders")
                        .with(accessToken)
                        .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(order))
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().is2xxSuccessful());

        mockMvc.perform(
                get("/ErPApI/orders")
                        .with(accessToken))

                .andExpect(jsonPath("_embedded.orders", hasSize(1)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("_embedded.orders[0].salesMemo", is("some sales memo")))

                .andReturn();


    }

}
```

the post is successful but the response body is blank. Is there a way to simulate the real response with MockMvc? Is my setup wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set the `Accept` header to `application/json` too in the request.

Comment: this is not required when not mocking the server though right? just checking.

Comment: There is also a property which could force returning the new object. `spring.data.rest.return-body-on-create=true` and
`spring.data.rest.return-body-on-update=true`. If it's defined then tha't the rule. Otherwise the result is returned only if the Accept header was set.